# get average of wifi scans

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on developing an android App and I have the following code that scans for avalible access points and save it to a text file:

```
for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResults) {
string.append(String.format("%s|%s\n", scanResult.BSSID, scanResult.level));
}
```

before the data is saved into a text file I would like to get several scanResult.level (for example 10) get the average and then save it to the text file.

any recommendations on how to achieve this?

I was thinking on this:

```
for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResults) {
 vector[scanResults]=scanResult.level
}
wait(100)
for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResults) {
 vector1[scanResults]=scanResult.level
}
wait(100)
for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResults) {
 vector2[scanResults]=scanResult.level
}
wait(100)

and then vectorfinal=(vector+vector1+vector2)/3
```